# react to node changes (python)

Tags: python, node-editor

What’s the most performant way to get the name of the node a user is interacting with (not selecting, changing the nodes parameters only)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Context.active_node`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=active_node#bpy.context.active_node) holds a reference to the *node in context* (the node that the user is interacting with). Example code based on the `operator_node.py` template that comes with Blender:

```
import bpy

class NodeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Node Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'

    def execute(self, context):
        print ("Node reference:", context.active_node) 
        print ("Node name:", context.active_node.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think my question was not clear enough.  I've amended the question.

Comment: No problem. However, your question is way different now. Do you mind just asking a new one? The initial question wasn't that bad obviously, gained a lot of attention and votes (even it was a low quality question showing no effort) so might be useful to leave it as it was. @user3597862

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229202/call-a-function-that-prints-the-name-of-the-node-that-the-user-is-changing-a-par