# Call a function that prints the name of the node that the user is changing a parameter on?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, performance

What’s the most performant way to call a function every time a user changes a parameter on a compositor node (even if the node isn't selected), and get the name of that node in the function which is called?

This is what I have so far, but I guess it's not very performant to call the function for every depsgraph change. I'm guessing message bus would be the most appropriate but what message?

```
import bpy    
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


@persistent
def desgraph_post(dummy):
    
    try:
        context = bpy.context
        print ("Node name:", context.active_node.name)
    except:
        print('context is not a node tree')


bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(desgraph_post)
```

Comment: AFAIK no joy re `msgbus` and context properties.  Subscribing to `bpy.types.Nodes` `"active"` is prob the emulation of above, but will only fire when active node is changed, not a property within. (or if removed https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/run-function-on-material-node-tree-update)

Comment: also would check the arguments available. Load handlers are often given `dummy` as an argument as during load restricted context limits the availability of bpy data. Others will have `scene, depsgraph` as arguments.   In the old days (pre 2.8) the active object is also `scene.objects.active`.  _ie_  not mixing context with handlers. If the depsgraph of another non context scene is changed, hander above  will report the active node of the context scene.